# PHP - DOM - XML - Nodes with similar attribute manipulation

Tags: php, xml, dom, dom-manipulation

I have to manipulate a XML file with DOM

This is my situation:

```
<mainnode>
<node1  name="aaa">
           <subnode   name="123456" />
    </node1>

    <node1  name="bbb">
           <subnode   name="28472" />
    </node1>

    <node1  name="aaa">
           <subnode   name="92328" />
    </node1>

    <node1  name="ccc">
           <subnode   name="53554" />
    </node1>

    <node1  name="ccc">
           <subnode   name="01928" />
    </node1>

    <node1  name="aaa">
           <subnode   name="39576" />
    </node1>

    <node1  name="ddd">
           <subnode   name="66666" />
    </node1>
</mainnode>
```

And I want to group all my nodes reading the "name" attribute in `<node1>` to obtain something like this for every "name" equal to another one:

```
<mainnode>    
<node1 name="aaa">
          <subnode   name="123456" />
          <subnode   name="92328" />
          <subnode   name="39576" />
    </node1>


    <node1  name="bbb">
          <subnode   name="28472" />
    </node1>

    <node1  name="ccc">
          <subnode   name="53554" />
          <subnode   name="01928" />
     </node1>

    <node1  name="ddd">
          <subnode   name="66666" />
    </node1>
</mainnode>
```

What is the php code to do this kind of manipulation with dom? is it possible?

Comment: Is it possible? **Yes**. What is the php code to do this kind of manipulation? http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php . What have you tried?

Comment: the XML doesnt have a root node

Comment: @gordon: root node added, btw my code was just to give an example

Comment: its still invalid though. the subnodes should be `<subnode/>` or have a closing `</subnode>`. even when its just an example. if you provide invalid xml you are adding barriers for people who want to help.

Comment: @rdlowrey I've tried to read the nodes by reading the attributes with getElementsByTagName, but i cannot reach to group all the different nodes

Comment: @Gordon. you're right, in fact in the original files the nodes are closed (i've fixed it also here) in any case, don't mind at some possible little mistake in this code i've reported, because it's not the file i'm working with, it's just an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this (please ensure that your XML is normalized before):

```
// load the xml and prepare the dom
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

// do not display parsing errors to the user
libxml_use_internal_errors(true)

// load xml
$dom->loadXML($string);

// optionally handle parsing errors provided in libxml_get_errors()

// store the node names
$nodeNames = array();

// get all nodes
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('node1');


foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
    /* @var $node DOMElement */
    $nodeName = $node->getAttribute("name");

    if (isset($nodeNames[$nodeName]))
    {
        /* @var $previousNode DOMElement */
        $previousNode = $nodeNames[$nodeName];

        if ($node->hasChildNodes())
        {
            foreach ($node->childNodes as $childNode)
            {
                $previousNode->appendChild($childNode);
            }
        }

        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
    else
    {
        $nodeNames[$nodeName] = $node;
    }
}
```

Comment: the correct way to suppress parsing errors is to use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)`

Comment: @ Gordon I added it to my answer. The @ operator was just a dirty hack to see, whether the example code actually works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP XQuery extension in order to do this:

```
let $data := (: your xml :)
return
    element mainnode {
        for $nodes in $data/node1
        let $name := string($nodes/@name) 
        group by $name 
        return
         element {$name} {
             attribute name {$name},
            for $node in $nodes
            return $node/subnode 
        }
    }
```

You can try the example live at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#TuRqsG1GZewGQD3f0QhmsIpVmTc=
Instructions on how to install the XQuery extension on PHP is available at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/entry/2011/12/27/PHP_Meets_XQuery

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$xml` holds your XML string ([demo](http://codepad.org/1kUWgSaq)):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
// iterate all the subnodes
foreach ($xpath->query('/nodes/node1/subnode') as $subnode) {
    // get the subnodes parent node's name attribute
    $name = $subnode->parentNode->getAttribute('name');
    // fetch the first node element with that name attribute
    $node = $xpath->query("/nodes/node1[@name='$name']")->item(0);
    // move the subnode there
    $node->appendChild($subnode);
}
// iterate over all node1 elements that are now empty
foreach($xpath->query('/nodes/node1[not(*)]') as $node) {
    // remove them
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
// print new dom tree
$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Note that I am assuming the root node to be `<nodes>`.